# How can I resolve crash Thread SIGSEGV 0x0000000000000010 in react native

Tags: firebase, react-native

I have an application published in Play Store,
I got a crash report but I can't figure out how to resolve it,
Trace:

```
Crashed: Thread: SIGSEGV  0x0000000000000010
   at (Manquant)()
   at (Manquant)()
   at (Manquant)()
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this is the same, but worth checking out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65418985/react-native-crashedthread-sigsegv-libjsc-so

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Crashed:Thread : SIGSEGV libjsc.so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65418985/react-native-crashedthread-sigsegv-libjsc-so)

Comment: Similar one here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63458449/android-app-crash-libjsc-so-missing-with-stacktrace-crashed-thread-sigsegv-0

Comment: Please Check thus question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65418985/react-native-crashedthread-sigsegv-libjsc-so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65418985/react-native-crashedthread-sigsegv-libjsc-so)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar incident once.
I used Android Studio - build and run the application in release for simulator, connect to the process and watch errors via logcat.