# Android App crash "libjsc.so" missing with stacktrace Crashed: Thread: SIGSEGV 0x0000000000000010

Tags: android, react-native

Our react-native App seems to sometimes crash on Android, PRD instance with error "`libjsc.so`" missing and the only details in Firebase are this:

Stack-trace:

```
Crashed: Thread: SIGSEGV  0x0000000000000010
   at (Missing)()
   at (Missing)()
   at (Missing)()
```

I will see about 6-10 occurrences of Firebase logs for this every day out of hundreds of logs in a day.

We can't reproduce the issue. Based on the Firebase log, the crash doesn't seem to happen on a particular screen but is most often seen after the App launch on the Login screen. This crash log wasn't seen before when the RN version was 0.59.9. I've recently upgraded our app to RN 0.61.5 and this seems to be a trending crash but with my Google searches, I am not finding anything that is close to this crash log.

**What I have tried:**

I thought that this may be related to Android 64bit support. So, I added the following in `app/build.gradle` but we are still seeing the same crashes even after releasing this fix.

```
packagingOptions {
    ...
    pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libjsc.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/x86/libjsc.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libjsc.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libjsc.so'
}
```

Hoping someone here could help/offer their thoughts about this issue.

Comment: I continue to see the same thing on `RN: 0.63.2` even after updating the android JSC. As an added data point, I am using the international variant of the JSC

Comment: We saw exactly the same error on Crashlytics with RN 0.61.23. Have you guys found any solutions? Is it worth to enable Hermes?

Comment: I haven't found any solution. Looks like even an upgrade to RN 0.63.* wont fix the issue.

Comment: I've also faced this crash in non-RN apps

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer, but I know how I would investigate:

1. Add some logging to determine which ABI's encounter the issue
2. Check for lib/{abi}/libjsc.so presence on startup.
3. Launch and close your app in a continuous loop, if it's a race condition it will probably happen rarely, but often enough over a number of app launches
   You will need a combination of adb scripting and a custom app version that closes itself after successful start. It might be possible with adb shell ps | kill.

```
Signal 11, also known as SIGSEGV (signal segmentation violation) is an 
error signal in Unix systems (Linux). The error appears when a program 
or code tries to access an invalid memory location. The operating system 
sends the signal 11 error to the program as a response.
```

Something isn't being initialized in time.

Once you reproduce the error:

4. Consult `adb logcat`, find anything you that looks like a crash your bundle identifier
5. Consult `adb logcat`, find anything you can related to `libjsc.so`
6. Disable everything in your app, you just need an empty screen with no react (if possible), see if you can reproduce the error
7. Add a minimal call that uses `libjsc.so`
8. scour the internet for `android thread 0x0000000000000010`, there's some other stuff there.

Full disclosure, I know nothing about `libjsc.so` ;)

Answer (score -1):

From my research it appears jsc has had [known crash issues](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25494) for some time now.

I would recommend trying out :

1. v8 - [React Native-v8](https://github.com/Kudo/react-native-v8)
2. **Hermes** - [Hermes](https://github.com/facebook/hermes) is a JavaScript engine optimized for fast start-up of React Native apps on Android.

For a more in depth performance comparison between the main memory profilers see [Medium blog](https://medium.com/walmartglobaltech/react-native-memory-profiling-jsc-vs-v8-vs-hermes-1626949a653b)