# React Native Crashed:Thread : SIGSEGV libjsc.so

Tags: android, react-native, android-native-library

We are getting following crash on various random places in android devices. Although we have changed ndk abifilters to "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"

```
  Crashed: Thread :  SIGSEGV  0x0000000000000010
  #00 pc 0x723d46f748 libjsc.so 
  #01 pc 0x723d4bbfe8 libjsc.so 
  #02 pc 0x7339d68b6c libc.so
```

Current configuration

RN version 0.63.4

```
 defaultConfig {
    ..
    ndk { abiFilters  "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a" }
}
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a",
                "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
    }
}

 project.ext.react = [
    entryFile   : "index.js",
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
 ]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: is hermes enabled in your build.gradle?

Comment: No hermes is disabled. Is this the root issue ?

Comment: Did you find the cause of this error? Any new ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have run into such issues in the wild with JSC only on Android RN 0.59.5, the only way forward was to upgrade JSC.

This problem is due to memory issues that occur deep in JSC and we can hardly do anything about it.

See these threads for more information:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24261

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/25426/files

But since you are already using RN version 0.63.4 the only way is to do away with JSC and enable Hermes. Hermes gives a lot of performance optimizations like byte-code, faster cold starts etc. Read more on that [here](https://engineering.fb.com/2019/07/12/android/hermes/).

If you want you can check the JSC version used in your app in the react-native/package.json and see if you can upgrade it further.

Comment: I have the same error on react-native 0.63.2, with jsc-android:^245459.0.0, and I have all changes from this post https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24261, but anyway get the error every time in the production mode. Any new ideas how to solve it?

Comment: same @satheesh any thing more that i should check

Comment: Guys enable hermes.

Comment: i have same issues and hermes is enable

Comment: This answer should not be accepted. same error here. Hermes is enabled, same crash.

Comment: @StefanMajiros this answer was posted when the OP had Hermes disabled. If you are getting this with Hermes then that is a different question. Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 7):

IF you are using webview and facing issue then put animationEnabled: false in screen where you got issue

```
<Stack.Screen
        name="CampaygnsDetail"
        component={CampaygnsDetail}
        options={{
          animationEnabled: false,
        }}
        />
```